# BreezeJS throwing error in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, breeze, durandal

I'm using BreezeJS on Durandal SPA framework application with EntityFramework + Asp.Net WebApi. I have hosted the application in Azure cloud hosting. I sometimes get error: NULLReference Exception on performing data fetch using breeze. This happens occasionally and not every time. And its not limited to one single Breeze query.

I thought it was connection drop and i tried with SQLAzureExecution Strategy - retry logic - but i still do get that error occasionally. Could anyone let me know what should i look into next

Comment: my first step would be to check the web browser console for any errors. also check that the web-api endpoint is returning what you are expecting.  the null reference exception may be hiding other errors.

Comment: yes Nathan,i found the NullReference exception by checking the browser console. If i use the breeze query either in browser or fiddler i am getting back what was expected.